# Comparing elements of two array in C

Tags: c

i want to compare one element of array to the second element the array "hello" word. if the i value gets the first element x[i] and y[i] they return correct result, but when they aren't same at the first place it isn't returning anything. myreturn function compares the two strings and return the same. where i am going wrong here?

```
char myreturn  (char x[],char y[])
{
    if (strcmp(x,y)==0)
        printf("%s ",x);
    else
        return 0;
}

main()
{
    char x[10][10]={"hello","super","everything"};
    char y[10][10]={"hero", "mind" ,"hello"};
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        if x[i] || y[j] != '\0')
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if (x[i] || y[j]=='\0')
        {
            myreturn(x[i],y[j]);
        }
}
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh: U wot?

Comment: Your `everything` string is an overflow, as you did not reserve a space for `'\0'`.

Comment: @sohel k As for me then I have understood nothing. What are you trying to achieve?!

Comment: Replace `char myreturn  (char x[],char y[])` -> `void myreturn  (char x[],char y[])` and `return 0;` -> `return;`

Comment: you use x[i]||y[j] but I cant find "j" anywhere whether defined nor increased/decreased

Comment: This question is of low quality, the snippet you gave us doesn't even compile.Flag it as 'low quality'.

Comment: `x[i]` and `y[i]` always(i|0..2) `!= NULL`

Comment: and `j` is undefind.

Comment: @Bathsheba my bad. sorry. removed the wrong comment.

Answer (score 0):

sample to fix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char x[10][16]={"hello","super","everything"};
    char y[10][16]={"hero", "mind" ,"hello"};
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        for(j=0; j<10; j++){
            if(*x[i] && *y[j] && strcmp(x[i], y[j])==0)
                printf("'%s' exist x[%d] and y[%d]\n", x[i], i, j);//'hello' exist x[0] and y[2]
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```